# patch method with axios to Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, api, vue.js

I'm having trouble qith "patch" method in vue 3

here's my frontend vue js script :

```
updateUser(){
  var formData = app.toFormData(app.currentUser);
  axios.patch('http://localhost/rest-server/api/user', formData).then(function(response){
    app.currentUser ={};
    if(!response.data.status){
      app.errorMsg = response.data.message;
    } else {
      app.successMsg = response.data.message;
      app.getUsers();
    }
  });
}
```

and my backend codeigniter 3 (btw i'm using rest server libraryy from here https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver  :

```
    public function index_patch()
    {
        $id = $this->patch('id');

        $data = [
            'first_name' => $this->patch('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->patch('last_name')
        ];

        if ($this->user_model->updateUser($data, $id) > 0) {
            $this->response([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'User updated successfully.'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            $this->response([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Failed to update.'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work, when i tried to echo the $id, it was null.

edit , itried to print the *$this->patch()*, and got this result :

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundary4IqCBGyVSGTaLv6P
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "id"

7
------WebKitFormBoundary4IqCBGyVSGTaLv6P
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"

Brilian
------WebKitFormBoundary4IqCBGyVSGTaLv6P
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"

Aldamaa
------WebKitFormBoundary4IqCBGyVSGTaLv6P
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="created_at"

2021-05-18 08:56:16
------WebKitFormBoundary4IqCBGyVSGTaLv6P
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="updated_at"

2021-05-18 08:57:34
------WebKitFormBoundary4IqCBGyVSGTaLv6P--

)
```

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using patch method from this library, you have to send JSON instead of form data as body of the request. Because this library is prepared for REST, where standard form of communication is JSON.